# How to send the contents of multiple MongoDB collections to a route for rendering using express?

Tags: mongodb, express

I have two mongoDB collections (players and opponents). I want to send the contents of both of them to the same route so I can use the values in different contexts.

I am using the following code but getting an error that `allPlayers is not defined`. I suspect the bigger problem though is that I can't send two datasets to `create` using `res.render` in the way I have.

Normally I would just use : `else {res.render (create,{allPlayers:players})}` after the error handling but obviously cant do this if I want to also send a second dataset.

I am newish to express/mongo etc so probably making a stupid mistake but any help would be appreciated.

```
app.get("/create", function(req,res){
  Player.find({}, function(err, allPlayers){
    if (err){
        console.log("There is an error")
    }
  });
  Opponent.find({}, function(err, allOpponents){
   if (err){
    console.log("There is an error")
   } 
  });
  res.render("create", {players: allPlayers, opponents: allOpponents});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following with your code. This should solve your issue (with the latest syntax). "allPlayers" was undefined because you were referencing it outside of the scope of the callback.

```
app.get("/create", async (req,res) => {
   const players = await Player.find({}, function(err, allPlayers){
       if (err){
           console.log("There is an error")
       }
   });
   const opponents = await Opponent.find({}, function(err, allOpponents){
      if (err){
          console.log("There is an error")
      } 
   });
   res.render("create", {players, opponents});
})
```

Comment: Thanks! But it is now giving me SyntaxError: Unexpected token (   - this is the ( after asynch? Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: app.get("/create", async (req,res) => {
                         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)

Comment: Ahh okay you need to install the latest version of node. 

https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/

Your version likely doesn't support the latest syntax. Download and install that, and let me know if it works. It will be good to have the latest version anyway!

Comment: I am working in Cloud9 so not sure how to intsall latest node. It is  v6.11.2. Is it possible to do using older syntax?

Comment: In your console type nvm i v10

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
app.get("/create", (req,res) => {
  Player.find({}, function(err, allPlayers){
   if (err){
       console.log("There is an error")
   }
   else{
      Opponent.find({}, function(err, allOpponents){
       if (err){
           console.log("There is an error")
         } 
        else 
          res.render("create", {players: allPlayers, opponents: allOpponents});
      });
    }
  });
});
```

You should wait for both the query to return you result before doing `res.render`. 
 I have added the queries in the `callbacks`.

Let me know if it helps.